# Keylock indicator for Xfce panel

Tags: indicator, keyboard-layout, xfce, xfce-panel

Is there a keylock indicator applet for Xfce panel (preferably native to Xfce)?

I have almost switched to Xfce, except for this!

Comment: [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867007) might help you with installing [this plugin](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin).

Answer (score 6):

The [keylock indicator plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin) for Xfce4 *"shows the state of your keyboard LEDs: Caps, Scroll and Num Lock in Xfce panel."*

**Installation instructions for Xfce4 keylock indicator plugin:**

(Note: This works on Xfce versions 4.6 and 4.8. Xfce 4.10 uses a different version of the `libxfce4ui` widget library and I haven't tested this plugin with 4.10).

**EDIT**: Tested and it works fine till Xfce versions 4.12.

- Download the files from [here](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin).
- Move to your download directory and unpack the files by running the following command:

  - `sudo tar -jxf xfce4-kbdleds-plugin-0.0.6.tar.bz2`
- Next, change to the directory `xfce4-kbdleds-plugin-0.0.6` and run these commands:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr
   make 
  sudo make install
  ```
- Finally, add the plugin to your panel.

  -- The *Add New Items* dialogue can be opened by right clicking on an empty space on the panel and selecting *Add New Items*. If you right click on a space occupied by a panel plugin, you can access Add New Items by going to *Panel → Add New Items*.

[Source](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/add-new-items)

Comment: The GitHub repository for this doesn't include `configure`, but this one does, and it works with XFCE 4.12: http://archive.xfce.org/src/panel-plugins/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin/0.0/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin-0.0.6.tar.bz2

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the update with a new link. At the time, I may have used autogen.sh to compile. The last update, which you linked to, for this plugin was ~8 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions of @Kevin-Bowen did not work as is for me. This had to do with `sudo`. I adapted his instructions and turned it into a script to simplify the installation of the plugin. I have run the script under Ubuntu and Manjaro using Xcfe version 4.14.

The [Xcfe keylock indicator plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin) shows the state of the keyboard LEDs: Caps, Scroll and Num Lock in the Xfce panel.

Check [here](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin/releases) for the latest version and update the `PLUGIN_VERSION` in the script if necessary.

You can place the below code in a file or just copy & paste it into a terminal. I hope it helps someone.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup variables
PLUGIN_VERSION=0.0.6
PLUGIN_NAME=xfce4-kbdleds-plugin
PLUGIN_ARCH=${PLUGIN_NAME}-${PLUGIN_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Create a temporary directory under /tmp
TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d`

echo "Install Xcfe keylock indicator plugin [PLUGIN_ARCH=${PLUGIN_ARCH}, TMP_DIR=${TMP_DIR}]"

# Download the latest version
wget -P ${TMP_DIR} https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-kbdleds-plugin/archive/${PLUGIN_ARCH}

# Unpack the archive
cd ${TMP_DIR}
mkdir ${PLUGIN_NAME}
tar -xvzf ${PLUGIN_ARCH} -C ${PLUGIN_NAME} --strip-components 1
cd ${PLUGIN_NAME}

# Build and install
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

# Delete the temporary directory
cd ~
rm -rf ${WORK_DIR}
```

After running the code don't forget to enable the plugin:

1. Right click the Xcfe panel you want to place the plugin on
2. From the menu select `Panel > + Add New Items...`
3. From the dialog select `Kdbleds Plugin` and click the `+ Add` button